# http connector for Restlet and Apache http server

Tags: apache, http, restlet

I have figured out that to integrate calls between Apache HTTP server and Restlet, I need to write my own HTTP connector using the Restlet provided API's.

Is my assumption correct?
If I am wrong reply back with possible solutions.

I need suitable references that can guide me to write plugins for my above mentioned requirement.

thanks in advance!!!
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how you can have Apache set up as your public web server, but forward any or all requests on to a Restlet application for handling.

If that's correct, I don't think you need to write your own connector or plugin. Instead, you can just set up Apache to do reverse http proxying using the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive. (Don't forget to use [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) to automatically adjust some response headers.)

Comment: What if we want to do asynchronous polling?

Comment: @RaphMclee I’m afraid I don’t really understand your question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I wanted to use jetty and restlet to build a client application. I wanted to use the HttpExchange in the jetty and do the request asynchronously to have no thread blocked. I droped this idea and just implemented it in jetty alone.